# c# как распознать текущую ссылку?

Tags: c#, парсер

как распознать текущую ссылку, это просто ссылка или на файл?P.s. можно вариант, чтобы не пришлось качать весь html-код

Например: есть ссылка `someUrl.com` , а есть `someUrl.com/file.txt`. Как понять где файл?

Comment: ничего не понятно

Comment: @Zergatul есть ссылка http://someUrl.com , а есть http://someUrl.com/file.txt как понять где файл?

Comment: Можете выполнить HTTP метод `HEAD`: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#HEAD В таком случае сервер пришлет вам только заголовки. Вы смотрите на `Content-Type`, и узнаете, что находится по данному url.

Comment: @Zergatul кинь ответ, я помечу как правильный

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Что-бы проверить, что находится по конкретному url, не загружая при этом сам ресурс, можно выполнить HTTP метод HEAD. При этом сервер возвращает только HTTP заголовки. Нас интересует `Content-Type`. Пример кода:

```
var req = WebRequest.CreateHttp("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/");
req.Method = "HEAD";
var resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
Console.WriteLine(resp.ContentType);
```

Результат:

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```